# Actualización en SQLite

Tags: sqlite, update

Necesitaría hacer un update de una base de datos. Lo que intenté hacer algo con los campos de tipo texto pero recibo un error, con campo numéricos no tengo ningún problema.

```
miCursor.execute("update productos set precio=999 WHERE nombre='SHORT'")

miCursor.execute("update productos set precio=999 WHERE nombre='SHORT'")
```

La excepción:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: nombre

¿Qué podría ser?

Comment: Pega esto en el [google translate](https://translate.google.com/) a ver si lo entiendes mejor: `OperationalError: no such column: nombre`

Answer (score 0):

Fijate en tu consulta, especialmente en el campo "**nombre**" que se encuentra a lado del **WHERE**...

El error indica lo siguiente:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: nombre
```

Entonces, entiendo que no existe la columna "**nombre**" en tu base de datos **SQLite**. Verifica que tu tabla "**productos**" tenga el campo "**nombre**" que estás mencionando.